# Mappings between tensor products of group representations

Tags: representation-theory

All of my representations are on finite dimensional complex vector spaces.

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups. If $V$ is a representation of $G$ and $W$ is a representation of $H$, then $V\otimes W$ is a representation of $G\times H$.

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be $G$-reps, and let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be $H$-reps. There is a natural map
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_1,V_2)\otimes\mathrm{Hom}_H(W_1,W_2)\to \mathrm{Hom}_{G\times H}(V_1\otimes W_1,V_2\otimes W_2),
$$
which is always injective. Is there a simple criterion for when this map is an isomorphism? It would be an isomorphism if we were looking at spaces of all linear maps, rather than just the equivariant ones. I am particularly interested in pairs $(V_1,W_1)$ for which the map is an isomorphism for every choice of $V_2$ and $W_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural map is always an isomorphism, even if you replace $\mathbb C$ by any other field. (That said, the finite-dimensionality condition does matter.) See Exercise 4.1.9 (a) in [Darij Grinberg and Victor Reiner, *Hopf algebras in Combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v5](https://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v5/anc/HopfComb-v73-with-solutions.pdf). (A remark on notation, if you want to read the solution: If $G$ is a group and $g \in G$, then $t_g$ denotes the basis element of the basis $G$ of $\mathbb{C}G$ corresponding to $g$.)

Comment: That's great! I thought I had an example where the map wasn't an isomorphism, but I must have made a mistake.

Comment: Or I have :) Let me know if this is the case!